# Give BrowserWindow time to apply style changes

Tags: electron

In my electron BrowserWindow, I have a loader (spinner) to indicate the app is working.

```
<div class="loader" id="pleasewait" style="display: none;"></div>
```

When pressing a button, I want to display this element, then perform a long running function, and afterwards hide it again.

```
document.getElementById('pleasewait').style.display = 'block';
longRunningTask();
document.getElementById('pleasewait').style.display = 'none';
```

Unfortunately, the first call to display block is not shown to the user.
With this code I just never see the loader.

**Remark:** I also followed [this](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/deep-dive-into-electrons-main-and-renderer-processes-7a9599d5c9e2) post and encapsulated the `longRunningTask` in `electron-remote`, but no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to defer the execution of the rest of the code right after the next rendering stage, by using the function [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) with a delay value of 0 (by default):

```
document.getElementById('pleasewait').style.display = 'block';
setTimeout
(
    () =>
    {
        longRunningTask();
        document.getElementById('pleasewait').style.display = 'none';
    }
);
```

Comment: Yeah, 90% solved. But: if the element is fully hidden at startup, I cannot make it visible. However, if I initialize it with `opacity: 0.001;`, and set that to one instead of setting display to block, it works...